# Azure AKS monitoring

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

I am looking for an api method to pull AKS cluster utilization details, like cluster /pool /node  status,  cpu /memory utilization.

I couldn't find  any relevant method in AKS api. please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at View cluster [`metrics for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/view-metrics) if you want this as a API you can have a look at [Azure metrics rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/)